# How can I use .text or .html to write special character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, special-characters

I'm making a card game so I've made this script but I don't know why it doesn't output the symbols as ♥, but rather only `&hearts;` as a string, anyone knows why?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function makeCard(kind) {
    var
        card = $('<div>', { class: 'card' }),
        color = (kind == 'hearts' || kind == 'diams') ? 'red' : 'black',
        upper = $('<div>', { class: 'upper card-symbol ' + color, text: '\&' + kind + '\;' }),
        lower = $('<div>', { class: 'lower card-symbol ' + color, text: '\&' + kind + '\;' });

    card.append(upper).append(lower);
    card.appendTo('body');
}

makeCard('hearts');

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want html, not text:

http://jsfiddle.net/cxNqK/2/

```
    upper = $('<div>', {
        'class': 'upper card-symbol ' + color,
        html: '\&' + kind + '\;'
    }),
    lower = $('<div>', {
        'class': 'lower card-symbol ' + color,
        html: '\&' + kind + '\;'
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit (though it isn't my code). Please explain its purpose.

Comment: From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2): *The name `class` must be quoted in the object since it is a JavaScript reserved word, and `className` cannot be used since it refers to the DOM property, not the attribute.*

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention that. `class` is a reserved word in JavaScript. ECMAScript 5 allows using `class` as a variable name or a property, but in older browsers that do not support ES5 it throws an error.